# How can I monkey patch a function or method in groovy?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to modify an existing method in some Groovy code (Jenkins Pipeline) in order to extend its behaviour without changing the code that is consuming it.

Example the "sh" function where I do want to do something like (pseudocode):

```
  old_sh = sh
  def sh (args) {
    print(1)
    old_sh(args)
    print(2)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `metaClass` like so (note that the `decorator` can be used to decorate any method or closure not just sh):

```
def sh(Map args) {
    println "sh: $args"
}

sh(a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 2)

def decorator = { c, Map args ->
    println 1
    c(args)
    println 2
}

def decoratedSH = decorator.curry(this.&sh)
this.metaClass.sh = decoratedSH

sh(a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 2)
```

Comment: I am still trying to adapt this code to Jenkins Groovy as that's bit different but clearly it is a very good start.